# How to simplify memory read if I know register name

Tags: cocoa, reverse-engineering, lldb

I am trying to get argument values of a calling method:

```
@selector(processEditingForTextStorage:edited:range:changeInLength:invalidatedRange:)
```

I know how values are stored:

- $rdx - first argument
- $rcx - second argument
- $r8 - third argument (NSRange.location 8bytes)
- $r9 - third argument (NSRange.length 8bytes)
- $rbp+0x10 - fourth argument (NSUInteger 8bytes)
- $rbp+0x18 - fifth argument (NSRange.location 8bytes)
- $rbp+0x20 - fifth argument (NSRange.length 8bytes)

Is this correct?

Second question is there easier way how to print NSRange if I know where integers are stored? Something like "po *(NSUInteger *)($rbp+0x20)"

I get error for this:

```
(lldb) po *(NSRange *)($rbp+0x18)
error: incomplete type 'NSRange' (aka '_NSRange') where a complete type is required
forward declaration of '_NSRange'
```

required

```
(lldb)  memory read --size 8 --format x --count 1 ($rbp+0x20)
0x7fff5e348660: 0x0000000000000008
(lldb)  memory read --size 8 --format x --count 1 ($rbp+0x18)
0x7fff5e348658: 0x000000000000000a
(lldb)  memory read --size 8 --format x --count 1 ($rsp+0x8)
0x7fff5e348438: 0x000000000000000a
(lldb)  memory read --size 8 --format x --count 1 ($rsp+0x10)
0x7fff5e348440: 0x0000000000000008
```

Comment: "po *(NSRange *)($rbp+0x18)" - works fine in XCode 8.3.3. Xcode 9 beta doesn't like it.

Answer (score 2):

There are abbreviations for various commands that imitate GDB's commands. One of these is `x` (for "eXamine memory"), which is an abbreviation for "memory read". You can add a slash and format specifiers to use a specific format. For example `x/xg` formats an 8-byte value in hex. The argument is an expression for the address to examine.

So:

```
x/xg $rsp+0x10
```

Comment: Any input for calling arguments?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Do you mean do you have the correct expressions for the various arguments? Yes, I believe that's correct.